# Horizontal ScrollBar appearing only after completely scrolling down in ReportViewer when rendered in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, reportviewer

I have a reportviewer control inside a table . The problem is that the horizontal scroll bar for the report is shown only when I scroll completely vertically down in IE11. 
I want the horizontal scroll bar to be visible normally when the report is rendered without completely scrolling down.

It happens in IE11 only. It works perfectly fine in IE8.

Comment: please show your code effort .

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the issue. Seems like adding custom HTTP headers to IIS and web.config did the trick. I had to add EmulateIE8 headers to IIS and Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to make the changes in IIS or the web.config file, as you can place this tag in the head content of the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

If you're using a master page, you can drop this there and every content page you use will work as you're expecting here.